# Why select statement against a table in oracle returns ORA-04021

Tags: oracle, select, locking

I have a big partitioned, local indexed table in Oracle database, what I am doing is import a big dump file into it with `"impdp"`

Why when I issue a select statement against that table Oracle returns

> ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object

When a table is locked in Oracle, Why can't I execute Select statement against it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an Oracle bug.

Pure select can only be blocked by Library cache pin. But this should not be held forever.

See [ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object – Library Cache Pin](https://aprakash.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/ora-04021-timeout-occurred-while-waiting-to-lock-object-library-cache-pin/) by Anand or this note: Doc ID 1054939.6

*<sub>Originally left as a comment by [ibre5041](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/18697/ibre5041)</sub>*